# Rails returning all Conversation records, not just relevent ones.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a basic private messaging system for my application. I started with [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@danamulder/tutorial-create-a-simple-messaging-system-on-rails-d9b94b0fbca1) on Medium.

I discovered an issue though. It returns all conversations, not just the ones that the current user is actually involved in. The view only shows the ones you're in but all the records are there. Obviously that is horrible if you have more than a handful of users.

I've tweaked the controller to what I thought was the solution but I'm still getting all records so I'm thinking the issue is in the model.

**Conversations Controller**

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController

 before_action :authenticate_user!
 before_action :set_conversation, only: [:destroy]

 def index
  @user = current_user
  @conversations = Conversation.where(:sender_id == @user.id || :recipient_id == @user.id)
 end

 def create
  if Conversation.between(params[:sender_id],params[:recipient_id])
   .present?
    @conversation = Conversation.between(params[:sender_id],
     params[:recipient_id]).first
  else
   @conversation = Conversation.create!(conversation_params)
  end

  redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)

 end
```

**Conversation Model**

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :sender, :foreign_key => :sender_id, class_name: 'User'
 belongs_to :recipient, :foreign_key => :recipient_id, class_name: 'User'

 has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy

 validates_uniqueness_of :sender_id, :scope => :recipient_id

 scope :between, -> (sender_id,recipient_id) do
  where(sender_id: [sender_id,recipient_id], recipient_id: [sender_id,recipient_id]) 
 end

 def unread_message_nr_for(user_id)
     messages.where('messages.read = ?', false).where('messages.user_id != ?', user_id).count
 end

end
```

**Conversation View**

```
  <div class="ibox-content no-side-borders">
      <% @conversations.each do |conversation| %>
      <div class="conversation-member">
       <% if conversation.sender_id == current_user.id || conversation.recipient_id == current_user.id %>
       <% if conversation.sender_id == current_user.id %>
        <% recipient = User.find(conversation.recipient_id) %>
       <% else %>
        <% recipient = User.find(conversation.sender_id) %>
       <% end %>

            <span class="<%= 'current-conversation' if (params['conversation_id'].to_i == conversation.id) %>">
            <% if recipient.avatar.present? %>
            <%= image_tag(recipient.avatar_url(:navigation), class: "img-circle m-r-xs") %>
          <% end %>
              <%= link_to recipient.first_name + " " + recipient.last_name, conversation_messages_path(conversation)%>
            </span>
            <% if conversation.unread_message_nr_for(current_user.id) > 0 %>
              <span class="badge-inline">
                <%= conversation.unread_message_nr_for(current_user.id) %>
              </span> 
            <% end %>
       <% end %>
     </div>
     <% end %>
  </div>
```

**Conversations Schema**

```
  create_table "conversations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "sender_id"
    t.integer  "recipient_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

How can I get only the conversations where the current user is the sender_id or the recipient_id?

Comment: Instead of params[:sender_id],params[:recipient_id], shouldnt it be conversation_params[:sender_id] and conversation_params[:recipient_id]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use ruby in the `where` clause.  See the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions) for more info

```
Conversation.where("sender_id = ? OR recipient_id = ?", @user.id, @user.id)
```

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly. I wish it would have errored out on that line so I would have had something to go on. :)

Comment: You can do `Conversation.where(:sender_id == @user.id || :recipient_id == @user.id).to_sql` to see the sql that is generated